# terraform Interpolation mistake in vpc setup

Tags: terraform

guys I am trying to do an interpolation in interpolation. I have the following in my vars.tf file.

`variable "appname" {
  default = "application2"
}`

In my VPC I am trying to refer to my vpc by its name

`resource "aws_vpc" "${var.appname}" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}`

It is working good so far. So I am having a hard time with the subnet naming. How can I give a name for the subnet?

`resource "aws_subnet" "${var.appname-subnet}" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.${aws_vpc.var.appname}.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
}`

This line is being the problem for me. How can I refer to VPC in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think terraform allows interpolation in resource names.

You can give it any name & refer to it.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "yourvpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}


resource "aws_subnet" "yoursubnet" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.yourvpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
}
```

I know that this is quite obvious but I doubt if we can use interpolation in naming resources. You can remove/comment the subnet resource & try out just with the VPC with interpolation & see if it works.

In case you want to segregate resources for different environments, you can use terraform workspaces. It creates a different state file for every environment.
Ref - https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html

Issue - 
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1114

Comment: Many people just use `"this"` as the name for the only declaration of a certain type, i.e., `resource "aws_vpc" "this" { ... }`

Comment: Yes, it can be anything. It's just that there should be no duplicates for a particular resource.